# Environment variables file in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, environment-variables, ini

I'm new to C#, coming from a PHP background I'm accustomed to storing things like database/smtp config in an environment file excluded from source control, so that the application can run locally and in multiple environments. Is there an equivalent convention in C#/ASP.NET? Maybe an .ini file somewhere? Web.config is a possible candidate, but there is dependency information in there as well (like a composer.json), so maybe not.

Comment: Web config will do the trick.

Comment: Have you looked at rewrite rules for the web.config.  You should be able to setup a web.config for each environment, then use the publish feature to publish the version you want (with db and other environment changes)

Comment: Ah ok, `<applicationDependencies>` and publishing different versions should do the trick. Thanks guys. C# is great.

Comment: @OrenBaldinger you said that you're new to c#. So i can tell you that you're yet to see its greatness.

Comment: You are welcome to get your configuration information from anywhere. JSON files, config files, actual environment variables, querying a web server.

Comment: @user3185569 I can't tell you how I've longed for things like public readonly properties in PHP. hah. Nevermind the apparent glory that is LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

web.config is correct. You can add custom key/value pairs using the appSettings tag:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="CustomKey" value="Custom Value" />
</appSettings>
```

and then accessing it through:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]
```

[ASP.NET Web Configuration Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400235(v=vs.100).aspx)
[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx)